# WF 4 Activity private members thread safety

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I have a workflow that i load from db once the app starts, after that all i create a workflowinvoker instance  on the same workflow object and invoke it.

I understand that all the runtime specific information is contained with in ActivityContext, so any values i read/write to it would thread safe.

I am wondering if the private members of activities are also thread safe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The reason you must use the ActivityContext for all properties is so that the WF runtime is aware of the data stored and that data will be persisted and restored when needed. If you create your own private fields they will not play along.